Sylow subgroups of doubly transitive groups
Let $(G,X)$ be a doubly transitive permutation group (where $G$ acts faithfully on the set $X$). Let $x \in X$, and suppose that $\vert X \vert = n + 1$ is finite. Now let $p$ be a prime divisor of $n$, and consider any Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G_x$. It is known (and easy to prove) that $n_p$ (the largest power of $p$ that divides $n$) is the minimal size of a $P$-orbit in $X \setminus \{x\}$, and also that this size is attained (and only the transitivity of $G_x$ on $X \setminus \{ x\}$ is needed to show this).
Supposing that $G$ is not the symmetric or alternating group on $X$, can we say something about upper bounds of the size of $P$-orbits in $X \setminus \{ x\}$ without CFSG ?

What is $n_p$? And what do you mean by "upper bound of $P$-orbits"? Do you want to bound the number of $P$-orbits, or the size of them?

@NickGill: I edited the question.

I'm not sure what sort of upper bound you have in mind? We know that $G$ is affine or almost simple. In the affine case,  possibly barring the odd exception for small $n$, it seems clear that one can have $P$-orbits of size $|P|$ (so that's as large as possible). Likewise there are plenty of examples in the almost simple case where, again, one can have $P$-orbits of size $|P|$ (e.g. $PSL_2(q)$ acting on a set of size $q+1$). Do you have a conjectured form for your upper bound?

That's both times $n_p$ in your examples. I was hoping for an upper bound in terms of $n_p$ somehow ...

I see. Do you know what the correct bound is if you use CFSG?

If you look at $SL_d(2)$ acting on $2^d-1$ points and you take $P$ to be the Sylow $2$-subgroup of a point-stabilizer, then it looks to me like the orbit sizes of $P$ are $1,2,4,\dots, 2^{d-1}$ but $n_2=2$. I haven't actually proved this, but it seems to work... Seems like your desired upper bound doesn't exist... (But please do check! Maybe I've miscalculated.)
